# Definition of system call wrapper?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, hook, system-calls

Im currently studying operating systems using "Operating Systems: Three easy pieces".

I'm confusing with the terminology "system call wrapper". Since I am practicing system call hooking module programming in **x86_64 Linux with kernel version higher than 4.17** that has a system call wrapper.

What I learned system call wrapper from textbook was that **system call wrapper are defined in glibc**, but what i learned from internet about system call hooking was **for system call hooking, define a system call wrapper and place it into system call table**.

So what I'm confusing is that **what's the difference between syscall wrapper in glibc and syscal wrapper in syscall table**. or I'm just misunderstanding this terminology?

[image]

can you guys tell me the difference between these two (the one in libc and another in syscall table)?

Comment: I appreciate that using the same term for different things invites confusion, but surely the sources from which you learned the two uses of the term also described the two different kinds of wrappers to which they refer.  Certainly the diagram you present speaks directly to that.  So what is it that you actually want to know?

Comment: @JohnBollinger what's the difference between the two? and how can I differentiate two by name? (libc syscall wrapper and kernel syscall wrapper?) Is it right that the term "syscall wrapper" is used in both situations? thank you!

Comment: *how can I differentiate two by name?* -- I would suggest using the terms "userspace" and "kernel" to differentiating between the two kinds if you in fact use "sycall wrapper" to refer to both.

Comment: *Is it right that the term "syscall wrapper" is used in both situations?* -- you say it is.  I'm familiar with the terminology in conjunction with the userspace flavor.  Not so much with the kernel flavor, but it is plausible that the term is used there, too.